# Typescript Error on super(): expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I don't know what I need to do to resolve this TS error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

declare const Ink: any;

export default class TableOfContents extends Component <{ id: string }, { rendered: boolean }> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { rendered: false };
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I don't feel good about putting any here, what should it be?
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
> When implementing the constructor for a `React.Component` subclass, you
> should call `super(props)` before any other statement. Otherwise,
> `this.props` will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
> bugs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

So, you need to write:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { rendered: false };
}
```

You can also define interfaces for your props and state to fix all TS warnings and better intellisense:

```
interface IProps {
  id: string
}

interface IState {
  rendered: boolean
}

export default class TableOfContents extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      rendered: false,
    }
  }
}
```

If your editor complains and doesn't accept implicit `any`, you can set `"noImplicitAny": false` in [compilerOptions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in *tsconfig* file.